# Drive a DC motor with Infineon BTM7710G or BTS7710G

Tags: motor, dc, esp32

[image: SCHEMATIC]

Hi guys, i m trying to drive a dc motor 15Volt 0.4A with these components. I read in the DS that BTS7710G has 4 inputs IH1 IH2 IL1 IL2.  I dont know how to use these signal inputs , i  ve tried these combinations :

IH1:high IH2:Low IL1:pwm signal 5v  ---> btm becomes very hot
IH2:high IH1:Low IL2:pwm signal 5v  ---> btm becomes very hot
IH1:high IH2:Low IL1&IL2: 0v ---> i have a good square signal at the output bt when i connect the motor i got zero volt on the output. (see photo)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHO9B.jpg)

[image]

Can you help me how to use these 4 inputs? thanks a lot

Comment: You need to read about how to control deadtime during transition  to prevent shoot-thru

Comment: I don't find this as clever design.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and fix up your schematic so we can read it. Put the quality in up front and you'll benefit down the line. At the moment it only looks marginally better than some random lines. 
Some hints: power in on the left. GND symbols point downwards. No angled lines. Space everything out so it doesn't look cramped.Rotate Q1so the gate is on the left. Your schematic should have a 'flow' to it so the reader can easily understand what is coming in and how it is being sensed, switched etc.
Think about your choice of mosfet and whether the opto is of any use.

Answer (score 0):

It's my first schematic. The circuitry works great. I have found the issue. So, I`m posting the results in order to help each other.

Drive motor cw:

```
ih1 - high
ih2 - low
il2 - pwm signal
il1 - low
```

Drive motor ccw:

```
ih2 - low
ih1 - high
il1 - pwm signal
il2 - low
```